# OSX and installing Windows applications with Wine

Tags: macos, windows, wine

First time post here, so I do hope this goes in the right place.

I'm having a problem installing and running a Windows application on OSX. I've Googled quite a lot and tried various apps, but now I'm using Wine on OSX 10.9.5

To keep this question simple, Wine appears to have worked and the Windows install shield ran without (I think) any problem.

There's now a .lnk file on my desktop. If I run this using Wine, nothing appears to happen. If I look in the lnk file I see a typical path -

\Program Files\ and then name of application.

I cannot seem to find this path anywhere in OSX. I wanted to locate the executable and run it directly in Wine.

All I really want to do is run this Windows app, it's a simple enough program and really just a one off for me, so was trying to avoid heavyweight or expensive VM solutions.

I would really appreciate just any help on locating the \Program Files\ path, or another easy way of running a Windows application on OSX. I'm not very technical in this area so really am stuck!

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

Your Program Files should be here: ~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files which you can't see in the Finder (files/directories that begin with a period are hidden) unless you use the "Go to Folder..." feature in the Finder, but you can see it in the Terminal and launching your app with wine will be easier from the Terminal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wine creates a directory called `.wine/drive_c` in your home directory. Try this in the terminal:

```
ls '~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files'
```

Because `.wine` starts with a dot, this directory will be hidden in the Finder. I'm sure there is a way to make them show up, but I'm new to OS X so I just know the "Unix way".

Answer (score 1):

To show the hidden system files (and your path to the file for Wine):

Click on Go in the upper desktop bar then Utilities and run Terminal.

In Terminal paste:
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

Then paste:

killall Finder

This shows everything but be aware that you will have access to all sorts of files that can wreck your system if you mess with them.